# How to create a URL alias in htaccess on a Codeigniter site

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a client with a Codeigniter site, and it's set up so that pages on the site have urls like this:

`http://www.domain.com/shop/page/pagename`

which since this is a Codeigniter site is getting rewritten to:

`http://www.domain.com/index.php?/shop/page/pagename`

My client would like one particular page to have a url like this:

`http://www.domain.com/specialpage`

So I thought I could just add a RewriteRule to my htaccess like so:

```
RewriteBase /

# The new rule       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specialpage$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/shop/page/specialpage [PT,L]

# The usual Codeigniter rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]
```

But I get a 404 when I try to browse to `/specialpage`.  What am I missing?

I've also tried the following RewriteRules with the same result:

```
RewriteRule ^/?specialpage$ /shop/page/specialpage [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?specialpage$ index.php?/shop/page/specialpage [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?specialpage$ index.php/shop/page/specialpage [L,NC]
```

Comment: Why not just edit the route config?

Comment: Just remove index.php using .htaccess and use CI routing to do rest

Comment: D'oh, of course...